# minimum date among several columns

Tags: sql, count, min

I'm trying to get a count of a number of policies issued per month.  This is close to returning the correct information:

```
SELECT count(policy_no), left(issue_date,6)
FROM table_a
WHERE indicator = 'fln'
GROUP BY left(issue date,6)
```

the indicator is narrowing it down to the types of policies I want.  The only problem I'm having is that there will be an entry with an identical policy number every year as the policy renews.  I need to only count the lowest issue date for each policy, not every policy every time.  If a policy was issued in November of 2010, I want it to count that one time, not once for November 2010,2011,2012, etc.  The issue dates are in the format of yyyymmdd.  Only year and month are relevant.

I'm sure this is an easy one for the more experienced among you, I haven't been able to piece it together by other questions on this forum.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will get what you want:

```
SELECT LEFT(FirstIssued, 6) AS YYMM, COUNT(DISTINCT Policy_No) AS NumPolicies
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT Policy_No, MIN(issue_date) AS FirstIssued
      FROM table_a
    WHERE indicator = 'fln'
    GROUP BY Policy_No
  ) A
GROUP BY LEFT(FirstIssued,6)
```

The key is to first find the min date for each policy, before aggregating the counts.  Note that the only months you will have appear are those with at least one policy, so if you would prefer to have 0s you need to add in a date generator.